# DJANGO non nullable field migration issue

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Im a DJANGO/python novice. I have added two fields so that changes in enterprise and DJANGO admin are logged as who updated them and what date it was updated.

the constraint is that **these fields cannot be null**.

my changes are as follows:

```
   class Enterprise(models.Model):
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(
        null=False,
        auto_now=True,
        verbose_name='Last Updated Date',
        help_text="Points to time this was last modified",
    )

    last_updated_by = models.CharField(
        null=False,
        max_length=100,
        default='N/A',
    )
```

AND

```
class EnterpriseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Enterprise

    readonly_fields = (
        "last_updated",
        "last_updated_by",)

    fieldsets = ('last_updated','last_updated_by',),
```

however when I run pytest, I'm receiving an error: *null value in column "last_updated" violates not-null constraint*.

when I ran makemigrations, Django prompted me to add a default for last_updated:

`You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'last_updated' to enterprise without a default; we can't do that (the database needs something to populate existing rows). Please select a fix: 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows)`

so I chose option '1' and `default=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0),preserve_default=False,` is added to last_updated in my migration file.

```
    migrations.AddField(
            model_name='enterprise',
            name='last_updated',
            field=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, default=datetime.datetime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0), help_text='Points to time this was last modified', verbose_name='Last Updated Date'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
```

I was under the impression that the Unix epoch would be added as default in all existing columns.

Comment: What is your question? It seems like you already solved your problem by supplying a default value when running the migration

Comment: Exactly what version do you use? I can not reproduce this on Django-4.2 and IIRC, the current timestamp is used for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was under the impression that the Unix epoch would be added as default in all existing columns.

I tested this on [django-4.2](/questions/tagged/django-4.2) and it does, it of course might be the case that for some (very) old versions it is not the case.

Then you will need to provide a default value yourself, and the lucky part is, you can use `timezone.now`

Indeed, you can specify the current datetime with:

```
It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'last_updated' to enterprise without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.
Please select a fix:
 1) Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
 2) Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
Select an option: 1
Please enter the default value as valid Python.
The datetime and django.utils.timezone modules are available, so it is possible to provide e.g. timezone.now as a value.
Type 'exit' to exit this prompt
>>> timezone.now
```

This will then set the field to the timestamp at the moment the migration runs. That being said, it might be odd, since that is not the time the record got modified last, so perhaps `null=True` is a more sensical decision.

Answer (score 0):

When adding a new field to a model with an existing table Django needs a value to use for all the pre-existing rows.

If the field has a `default` specified that will be used and everyone is happy because that's nice and straightforward.

If the field is nullable and doesn't have a default value Django will set the column to null for existing rows. This obviously doesn't work for a non-nullable field.

Lacking either of those solutions Django asks you what it should do. It doesn't quietly set a non-null value on any field since that might have unintended effects.

Maybe you already have a command that checks enterprises, foos, and bars which runs every night. It uses a `getattr` to determine if the object has a `last_updated` attribute and deletes all the entries which were last updated twenty years ago or more. Setting the default value to 1970 in that case could unintentionally delete a large part of your database.